# Evaluating $\int_0^\infty\operatorname{erfi}(x)e^{-x^2}\frac{dx}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

I want to evaluate

> $$I=\int_0^\infty\operatorname{erfi}(x)e^{-x^2}\frac{dx}x$$
>   where $\operatorname{erfi}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^x e^{t^2}dt$.

I can only prove this integral converges.
**Not-so-useful Attempt**
Integrating by parts gives
$$I=\int_0^\infty-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{x^2}\operatorname{Ei}(-x^2)dx$$
Substituting $x^2=t$ gives $$I=\int_0^\infty-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi x}}e^{x}\operatorname{Ei}(-x)dx$$
where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the exponential integral function.

Comment: @Riemann No actually $\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt$ is $\operatorname{erf}$ function, $\operatorname{erfi}(x)$ is $\frac2{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^xe^{t^2}dt$.

Comment: OK, I  see now! Sorry for that .

Comment: @Kemono Try taking $\mathrm{erfi}(x) $ as the second function when integrating by parts because we have antiderivative of the imaginary error function as $$x\operatorname {erfi} (x)-{\frac {e^{x^{2}}}{\sqrt {\pi }}}.$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Introduce
$$
I(\lambda)=\int_0^\infty\mathrm{erfi}(\lambda x)\frac{\exp(-x^2)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
for $\lambda\in[0,1]$.  Note that $I(\lambda)$ is continuous (and even real-analytic on $(0,1)$) and differentiating with respect to $\lambda$ under the integral sign, we have
$$
I'(\lambda)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty\exp(-(1-\lambda^2) x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\lambda^2}}
$$
for $\lambda\in (0,1)$.  Furthermore, $I(0)=0$
and so
$$
I=I(1)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\lambda^2}}\,\mathrm{d}\lambda=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Comment: How did you introduce $\lambda$ in just the error function and not the whole integral ? You replaced $x$ with $\lambda x$ right?

Comment: This is a sort-of-standard trick, introducing a parameter $\lambda$ somewhere in the integrand (part of the trick is to come up with a good place to put it).  Subject to (1) typically $\lambda=1$ is what we want to evaluate, and (2) we know how to do some other value like $\lambda=0$.  If we can also get the derivative in a "nice" form that we can compute the definite integral, then we are done as in this case.  Another example, calculate $\int_0^\infty x^{-1}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x$, which you can do by introducing $I(\lambda)=\int_0^\infty x^{-1}e^{-\lambda x}\sin x\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Nice explanation and solution, $+1$

Answer (score 3):

A change of variable and Fubini's theorem are enough:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-x^2+y^2}\,dy\frac{dx}{x}&\stackrel{y\mapsto x z}{=}&\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{1}e^{-x^2} e^{x^2 z^2}\,dz\,dx\\&=&\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}=\frac{\pi}{2}. \end{eqnarray*}$$